# Chrome Extension: uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, import

When trying to export a value from "content.js" into my "popup-sign-in-script.js", I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

My content.js:

```
[Some Code]
export const userubi = userubi;
```

My popup-sign-in-script.js:

```
import {userubi} from './content.js';
[Some code]
```

The HTML file of popup-sign-in-script.js (popup-sign-in.html):

```
<script type="module" src="./popup-sign-in-script.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="./content.js"></script>
```

Comment: try reversing the order in which the script tags appear within the page as the import comes before the export

Comment: Didnt help, the order as far as I know makes no difference.

Comment: Content scripts are for web pages, not for the extension UI. Don't load it there, use a different script.

Comment: Im getting my userubi value from a website, so I have to put it inside my content script.

Comment: You need two different scripts. Content script for the web page and another different script for your extension UI. Use messaging or chrome.scripting or chrome.storage to pass the data.

Comment: What do you mean by extension UI, the only UI is the popup, which is in a different script alreeady as seen above